# How to get PLJSON working with other users

Tags: oracle, pljson

I just installed the latest version of PLJSON version 2.5.4

I successfully installed the packages on oracle with no error under the sys user, but other users can't access PLJSON for example running the test examples sql files.

ran as sys/sysdba

```
SQL> connect sys@backup as sysdba
Enter password: ********
Connected.
SQL> @C:\sql\pljson-3.6.1\examples\ex12.sql
"true"
"true"
"true"

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

running it from a different user results

```
SQL> connect orders@backup
Enter password: *****
Connected.
SQL> @C:\sql\pljson-3.6.1\examples\ex12.sql
  obj pljson;
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PLJSON' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 24:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PLJSON_PRINTER.PRETTY_PRINT_ANY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 24:
PLS-00201: identifier 'PLJSON_EXT.PP' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 17:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

how can i get it so all users can access it.

Comment: As an aside, creating objects in the `sys` schema is a bad idea.  `sys` is Oracle's schema.  It has special rules (and there are sometimes behaviors that are different for `sys` objects than for objects owned by a normal user).  Create a new schema to own this package if it doesn't make sense to install it in one of the existing schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used it, but - usually such a problem is resolved by granting privileges to other users - or even `public`. For example (connected as SYS and presuming package name is `pljson`)

```
grant execute on pljson to public;

create public synonym pljson for pljson;
```

Then you'd again connect as `orders` and run

```
@C:\sql\pljson-3.6.1\examples\ex12.sql
```